# Textarea, remove last paragraph

Tags: javascript, join, split, textarea

I would like to remove last paragraph from Textarea, but my script works only once - is there a way to remove last paragraph every time I click on button?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="V1" rows="17" cols="65">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Pellentesque sapien. 

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 

Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Duis viverra diam non justo. 

Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean placerat. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. In convallis.</textarea>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>

<script>
function remove() {
var elem = document.getElementById('V1'),
val = elem.value.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g);
val.pop();
elem.value = val.join('\r\n') + ('\r\n');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a `\r\n` sequence in the end. Subsequent calls will only remove that part. If you omit this and instead trim the text, it should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<textarea id="V1" rows="17" cols="65">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Pellentesque sapien. 

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 

Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Duis viverra diam non justo. 

Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean placerat. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. In convallis.</textarea>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>

<script>
function remove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('V1'),
  val = elem.value.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g);
  val.pop();
  elem.value = val.join('\r\n').trim();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
    <textarea id="V1" rows="17" cols="65">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Pellentesque sapien.
Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Duis viverra diam non justo. 
Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean placerat. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. In convallis.</textarea>
    
    <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
    
    <script>
        function remove() {
            var elem = document.getElementById('V1'),
        val = elem.value.split("\n");
            val.pop();
            elem.value = val.join("\n");
        }
    
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `filter()` method. When deleted, the spacing between the lines is preserved.

```js
function remove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('V1'),
  val = elem.value.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g).filter(function(i){
  return i;
  });
  val.pop();
  elem.value = val.join('\n\r');
}
```

```html
<textarea id="V1" rows="17" cols="65">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Quisque tincidunt scelerisque libero. Sed convallis magna eu sem. Pellentesque sapien. 

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. 

Integer imperdiet lectus quis justo. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Duis viverra diam non justo. 

Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean placerat. Nullam justo enim, consectetuer nec, ullamcorper ac, vestibulum in, elit. In convallis.</textarea>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `filter` the empty strings, cuz `pop` gets rid of the last item of an array, but sometimes your last item is this: `""`

To achieve that, I used **double bang** or **!!** which returns a boolean based on the value.

More info about double bang: https://medium.com/better-programming/javascript-bang-bang-i-shot-you-down-use-of-double-bangs-in-javascript-7c9d94446054

Because of this, I added +1 `\r\n` to `join` to keep the empty lines.

```
function remove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('V1');
  var val = elem.value.split(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g).filter(paragraph => !!paragraph);

  val.pop();

  elem.value = val.join('\r\n\r\n');
}
```